# Zoho live chat widget in React Js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, zoho

I am trying to test Zoho live chat widget code in `react js`, below is the sample code

```
 <a href={void(0)} onClick={()=>window.$zoho.salesiq.floatwindow.visible("show")}>LIVE CHAT</a> 
        
 window.$zoho = window.$zoho || {};window.$zoho.salesiq = window.$zoho.salesiq || {widgetcode:"XXXXXXXXXX", values:{},ready:function(){}};

 let  d= document;

 let s = d.createElement("script");
   s.type ="text/javascript";
   s.id ="zsiqscript";
   s.defer = true;
   s.src = "https://salesiq.zoho.eu/widget";

 let t = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
   t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);

 d.write("<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>");

 window.$zoho.salesiq.ready = function()
 {
   window.$zoho.salesiq.floatwindow.visible("show");
}
```

Above is the code written and with on click of Live chat, a link should display the live chat widget. Now I am not getting any errors or not displaying the Zoho button. Please help if it is the correct way to test in react js.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
import React from "react";

// Zoho Sales IQ widget code
export default function ZohoSalesIQ(props) {
    window.$zoho = window.$zoho || {};
    window.$zoho.salesiq = window.$zoho.salesiq || {
        widgetcode: process.env.REACT_APP_ZOHO_SALESIQ_CODE,
        values: {},
        ready: function () {},
    };
    const d = document;
    let s;
    s = d.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.id = 'zsiqscript';
    s.defer = true;
    s.src = 'https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget';
    let t;
    t = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id='zsiqwidget'></div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Be sure to declare the widget access code in your `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

import React, {useEffect } from "react";

function UserSupport() {

```
useEffect(() => {
    const url = 'https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget';
    const widgetCode = 'a4af5eb95281904723549d6ff5177dc61fb4b3c5a9944856ba17f7c864fa';
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("id", "scriptid");
    let code = `var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {widgetcode: "${widgetCode}", values:{},ready:function(){}};var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;s.src="${url}";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.innerHTML = "<div id='zsiqwidget'></div>";`
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
        document.getElementById('scriptid').remove();
        document.getElementById('zsiqscript').remove();
    }
},[])

const showChat = () => {
    document.getElementById('zsiq_float').classList.remove('d-none');
    document.getElementById('zsiq_agtpic').click();
}

return (
    <>
    <style>{`
        .zsiq_theme1.zsiq_floatmain {opacity: 0 !important; pointer-events :none; display:none !important;}
        .siqanim{
            transform: scale(1)!important;
        }
    `}
    </style>
        <div className="col-md-3" onClick={showChat} role="button">
            <h2 className="fs-5 fw-bold pt-3">Live Chat</h2>
        </div>
    </>
)
```

}

export default UserSupport

Comment: in style.css paste this code for showing your chat only onclick on that window , if you to another window it will be hide       .siqico-chat{
  display: none;
}


.zsiq_theme1.zsiq_floatmain, .logedin .zsiq_theme1.zsiq_floatmain{
  min-height:60px;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  display: none !important;
}
.siqanim, .logedin .siqanim{
  transform: scale(0)!important;
}

Comment: This will work only onclick event of a button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).